# Extract Public Key using pyOpenSSL from certificate or other connection information

Tags: python, twisted, public-key, pyopenssl

I'm currently trying to write a python server script which should authenticate the current client based on its public key. Since I'm using twisted, the [example in the twisted documenteation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html#auto7) got me started.

While I can generate keys, connect and communicate using the example code, I have not yet found a way to get the public key of the client in a usable format. In [this stackexchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362965/how-to-get-public-key-using-pyopenssl) somebody extracts the public key from an `OpenSSL.crypto.PKey` object but cannot transform it to a readable format. Since in I have access to the `PKey` object of the x509 certificate in the `verifyCallback` method or via `self.transport.getPeerCertificate()` from any method of my Protocol, this would be a good way to go. The (not accepted) answer suggests to try `crypto.dump_privatekey(PKey)`. Unfortunately, this does not really yield the expected result:
While the `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` and `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` in the answer could be fixed by an easy text replacement function, the base64 string seems not match the public key. I've extracted the public key with `openssl rsa -in client.key -pubout > client.pub` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271197/openssl-how-to-extract-public-key). It does not match the result of the `dump_privatekey` function.

While there still is an [open bug towards OpenSSL on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyopenssl/+bug/780089), it is not yet fixed. It was reported 19 Month ago, and there is some recent (October 2012) activity on it, I do not have any hope of a fast fix in the repos.

Do you have any other ideas how I could get the public key in a format comparable to the `client.pub` file I have mentioned above? Perhaps there is a twisted or OpenSSL connection specific object which holds this information. Please note that I have to store the public key in the protocol object such that I can access it later.

### Why is no Answer accepted?

#### M2Crypto by J.F. Sebastian

Sorry, that I had not thought of a possibility where I cannot correlate the certificate to the connection. I've added the requirement that I have to store the public key inside the protocol instance. Thus, using `peerX509.as_pem()` inside the `postConnectionCheck` function as suggested by J.F. Sebastian does not work. Furthermore, at least in version 0.21.1-2ubuntu3 of python-m2crypto I have to call `peerX509.get_rsa().as_pem()` to get the right public key. Using `peerX509.as_pem(None)` (since `peerX509.as_pem()` still wants a passphrase) yields excactly the same output as `crypto.dump_privatekey(PKey)` in PyOpenSSL. Maybe there is a bug.

Besides this, the answer showed me a possible way to write another workaround by using the following `Echo` protocol class:

```
class Echo(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        """As soon as any data is received, write it back."""
        if self.transport.checked and not self.pubkeyStored:
            self.pubkeyStored = True
            x509 = m2.ssl_get_peer_cert(self.transport.ssl._ptr())
            if x509 is not None:
                x509 = X509.X509(x509, 1)
                pk = x509.get_pubkey()
                self.pubkey = pk.get_rsa().as_pem()
                print pk.as_pem(None)
            print self.pubkey
        self.transport.write(data)
```

As you can see this uses some internal classes which I'd like to prevent. I'm hesitating submitting a small patch which would add a `getCert` method to the `TLSProtocolWrapper` class in M2Crypto.SSL.TwistedProtocolWrapper. Even if it was accepted upstream, it would break compatibility of my script with any but the most cut-of-the-edge versions of m2crypto. What would you do?

#### External OpenSSL call by me

Well, its an ugly workaround based on external system commands just which seems to me even worse than accessing non-public attributes.

Comment: Related, see [Upgrading my encryption library from Mcrypt to OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43329513/608639), [Replace Mcrypt with OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9993909/608639) and [Preparing for removal of Mcrypt in PHP 7.2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42696657/608639)

Answer (score 6):

Some of previous answers produce (apparently?) working PEM public key files, but so far as I've tried, none of them produce the same output that the 'openssl rsa -pubout -in priv.key' does. This is pretty important to my test suite, and after poking around in the (0.15.1) PyOpenSSL code, this works well for both standard PKey objects and the public-key-only PKey objects created by the x509.get_pubkey() method:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
from OpenSSL._util import lib as cryptolib


def pem_publickey(pkey):
    """ Format a public key as a PEM """
    bio = crypto._new_mem_buf()
    cryptolib.PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(bio, pkey._pkey)
    return crypto._bio_to_string(bio)


key = crypto.PKey()
key.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)
print pem_publickey(key)
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this works a little better @jessica-gadling

Answer (score 2):

The analog of `openssl rsa -in client.key -pubout > client.pub` command in [`M2Crypto`](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto) (a more complete openssl wrapper than pyOpenSSL) is:

```
def save_pub_key(cert, filename):
    cert.get_pubkey().get_rsa().save_pub_key(filename)
```

You can use `M2Crypto` instead of `pyOpenSSL` with twisted. To add ssl capabilities to the echo server:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()
```

You could:

```
import sys
from twisted.python import log

from M2Crypto import SSL, X509
from M2Crypto.SSL import Checker
from M2Crypto.SSL.TwistedProtocolWrapper import listenSSL

log.startLogging(sys.stderr)    
cert = X509.load_cert('client.crt')
check = Checker.Checker(peerCertHash=cert.get_fingerprint('sha1'))

def postConnectionCheck(peerX509, expectedHost):
    log.msg("client cert in pem format:\n", peerX509.as_pem())
    save_pub_key(peerX509, 'client.pub')
    return check(peerX509, host=None) # don't check client hostname

class SSLContextFactory:
    def getContext(self):
        ctx = SSL.Context()
        ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile='ca.crt')
        ctx.load_cert(certfile='server.crt', keyfile='server.key',
                      callback=lambda *a,**kw: 'keyfile passphrase')
        ctx.set_verify(SSL.verify_peer | SSL.verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert,
                       depth=9, callback=None)
        return ctx
listenSSL(8000, EchoFactory(), SSLContextFactory(),
          interface='localhost',  reactor=reactor,
          postConnectionCheck=postConnectionCheck)
reactor.run()
```

To try it, create self-signed certificates:

```
$ openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out server.crt -keyout server.key
# NOTE: server.key is unencrypted!
$ cp {server,client}.crt
$ cp {server,client}.key
$ cp {server,ca}.crt
```

and connect to the server:

```
$ openssl s_client -cert client.crt -key client.key -CAfile ca.crt \
   -verify 9 -connect localhost:8000 -no_ssl2
```

The server saves the client's public key to the `client.pub` file. It is identical to the one created by `openssl` command:

```
$ openssl rsa -in client.key -pubout > openssl_client.pub
$ diff -s {openssl_,}client.pub
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to get the public key is an ugly workaround by piping the pem version of the x509 certificate through an externally called openssl instance:

```
def extractpublickey(x509):
    x509pem = dump_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM,x509)
    ossl = Popen(['openssl','x509','-pubkey','-noout'] , stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
    (stdout,_) = ossl.communicate(x509pem)
    res = ""
    if stdout[:26] != ("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----") or stdout[-24:] != ("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"):
        raise AttributeError("Could not extract key from x509 certificate in PEM mode: %s"%x509pem)
    else:
        res = stdout
    return res

class Echo(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        """As soon as any data is received, write it back."""
        if self.transport.getPeerCertificate() == None:
            print("unknown client")
        else: 
            print extractpublickey(self.transport.getPeerCertificate())
        self.transport.write(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it working finally using pyOpenSSL and DerSequence class from Crypto.Util.asn1 (pyasn1 library).

Here is a method from my RSAKey class (pkey is a OpenSSL.crypto.PKey instance)  :

```
from OpenSSL.crypto import dump_privatekey, FILETYPE_ASN1
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Util.asn1 import DerSequence
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode

...

def fromPKey_PublicKey(self, pkey):
    src = dump_privatekey(FILETYPE_ASN1, pkey)
    pub_der = DerSequence()
    pub_der.decode(src)
    self.key = RSA.construct((long(pub_der._seq[1]), long(pub_der._seq[2])))
```

The key here is that first item in pub_der._seq is zero and we dont need it.
Than you can convert RSA key stored in self.key to any format you want:

```
def toPEM_PublicKey(self):
    pemSeq = DerSequence()
    pemSeq[:] = [ self.key.key.n, self.key.key.e ]
    s = b64encode(pemSeq.encode())
    src = '-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n'
    while True:
        src += s[:64] + '\n'
        s = s[64:]
        if s == '':
            break
    src += '-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----'
    return src
```

I am currently working with CSpace project, it uses "ncrypt" library ( this is another OpenSSL wrapper ) wich is not supported anymore and it gives SegFault on Linux. So I decided to replace ncrypt library with pyOpenSSL because I am using it in my project called DataHaven.NET. And getting a public key from the peer certificate in PEM format really was a problem for me. Now it is working just fine.